# jquery hide input element error

Tags: jquery

The initial idea, is to hide an input element and show it based on a change event in a select element. However, the code I have is not hiding the input and so nothing happens with the change statement. Could someone check the code and show me my error. Thanks

```
<label for="AUSR_companyname">Company Name:</label>
<input id="AUSR_companyname" name="AUSR_companyname" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox AUSR_companyname" value = "" />


!--- dropdown for new user addition  -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $("#AUSR_companyname").hide();
            $(function() {
            jQuery("#AUSR_company").live('change', function() {
                  if($(this).val()=="new")
                 {
                    $("#AUSR_companyname").show(); 
                }
            });
      });
</script>
<!--- end of dropdown for new user addition -->
```

++++UPDATE++++

This script is now causing error 'missing ) after argument list'. Where have I missed it? Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $("#AUSR_companyname, label[for=AUSR_companyname]").hide();
            jQuery('#AUSR_company").live('change', function() {
                  if($(this).val()=="new")
                 {
                    $("#AUSR_companyname").show(); 
                }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Just seen my error. Need to move into the ready function.

Comment: There is one other thing. How do I hide a label along with the input field? Thanks

Comment: See my edit below @bollo

Comment: Oh, I'm just a second to late ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using jQuery. Take care that you have included the jQuery-files in the html header section.

After that, wrap your javascript code into the jQuery ready function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#AUSR_companyname").hide();
        $(function() {
        jQuery("#AUSR_company").live('change', function() {
              if($(this).val()=="new")
             {
                $("#AUSR_companyname").show(); 
            }
        });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

EDIT: to answer your question you posted in your comment block:
To hide the label, too you could use something like this:

```
$('label[for="AUSR_companyname"], #AUSR_companyname').hide();
```

Comment: Yeh, I posted probably a fraction behind you :-) when I realised my error. Do you have any advice re my other comment about the label? thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, wrote [for="AUSR_company"] instead of [for="AUSR_companyname"]. edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/9vVah/

Something else must be affecting the code

**EDIT**

In response to this comment you just added

> There is one other thing. How do I hide a label along with the
>   input field?

Do this

```
 $("#AUSR_companyname, label[for=AUSR_companyname]").hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/9vVah/1/

Comment: Jason, now I moved it into the ready function, it is working. Just need to find an answer to the label problem which I posted as a comment. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Jason. Is this the correct way to chain elements that need to be hidden or is there more elegant way? $("#AUSR_companyname, #AUSR_name, label[for=AUSR_companyname],label[for=AUSR_name]").hide();

Comment: No, this is it.  Just separate them by commas.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues with the code, other than saying wrap everything under `jQuery.ready` block: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/7Rsce/

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me,

I took the liberty to enclose the input and label in a div, and add the select: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jasalguero/UL8EE/)